# Formvalidation / Correction as you type: Initials

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I would like to autocorrect a field for initials, but my knowledge is limited, so after an hour of trial and error, all I have is a small script that just uppercases the input. What I would like is this:

- a becomes A. (uppercase and ends with a dot)
- AbC becomes A.B.C.(uppercase and seperated by a dot)
- A1BC_* becomes A.B.C. (no other characters allowed, uppercase and seperated by a dot)

What I have is this:

```
    $(".hoofdletters").keyup(function(e)
    {
        $(".hoofdletters").val(($(".hoofdletters").val()).toUpperCase());
    });
```

**Update**

I don't want to waste anyones time and open a new topic, so i try it here. I tried something myself as well to automatically capitalize every word in a sentence. Everything is working, but for some reason the space get's deleted. It has something to do with  `+ ''` If i delete that nothing works anymore, if i add a space i get a space after every letter and if i leave it this way, then spaces are not allowed.

Anyone any suggestion?

```
$('.cap').bind('textchange', function (event, previousText) {
        var val = this.value;
        var newVal = '';
        val = val.split(' ');
        for(var c=0; c < val.length; c++) {
                 newVal += val[c].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() +
 val[c].substring(1,val[c].length) + ''; // It has something to do with this line
        }
        this.value = newVal;
    });​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9znp/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hoofdletters").focus(function() {
        var current = $(".hoofdletters").val();
        $(".hoofdletters").keyup(function(e) {
            var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            console.log(e.keyCode);
            if (key >= 'A' && key <= 'Z') {
                current += key + ".";
                this.value = current;
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == 8) {
                current = $(".hoofdletters").val();

            } else {
                current = "";
            }
        });
        $(".hoofdletters").blur(function() {
            var i = $(".hoofdletters").val();
            var last = i[i.length - 1];
            if (last != "." && i.length !== 0) {
                this.value += ".";
            }
        });
        $('.hoofdletters').keydown(function(e) {
            var i = $(".hoofdletters").val();
            if (e.keyCode == 8 && i.charAt(i.length - 1) == ".") {
                $(".hoofdletters").val(i.slice(0, -1));
                current = $(".hoofdletters").val();
            }
        })
    });
});​
```

Comment: Sorry to bug you after a long while, but is it also possible that when someone deletes something, it deletes a pair of a capital and a dot. E.g. When someone types A.B.C. and clicks backspace, it deletes C. as a pair. I think it will be hard..

Comment: @mat, threw that together. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, fantastic work! If i can do anything for you let me know.

Comment: This snippet has a bug. When I enter a capital, it resets the whole value @pmandell

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not a place to find people to write code for you, let me give you a plan you can follow to approach the problem. Then, if you come across problems along the way, you can come back here with a much more concrete question.

- You use a variable to store your output, this variable starts as an empty string
- You loop through all the letters

  - If the letter is allowed, add the upper case version of it to the end of your output variable
- Set the new value of your input box equal to the output variable.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

**Code**:

```
$(".hoofdletters").keydown(function(e) {
    var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toUpperCase();
    if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        this.value += c.toUpperCase() + ".";
        return false;
    }
    return false;
});​
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/aHq4b/

---

**Note:** The above strategy has the following limitations.

- It completely blocks regular actions like delete/backspace etc. as we are completely controlling the keydown event, leaving nothing to the browser to perform.
- It always appends the character at the end, instead of inserting at the cursor position
- It doesn't support paste action

The following should rectify those as well. It uses zurb's textchange event which fires whenever text changes regardless of the means (pase/type/text-drag-drop etc.)

**Code**:

```
$('.hoofdletters').bind('textchange', function (event, previousText) {
    var t = this.value;
    var newValue = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        var c = t.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
        if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            newValue += c + '.';
        }
    }
    this.value = newValue;
});​
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/aHq4b/1/

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. I am now reading into what jquery.textchange.min exactly is, because it didn't work without it. Thanks for the help i accepted and upvoted, it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you like a little shorter code, perhaps this would work for you.

```
string.replace(/([a-z])([^a-z]*)/gi, '$1.').toUpperCase();
```

> Examples below...

```
var string = 'a';
string.replace(/([a-z])([^a-z]*)/gi, '$1.').toUpperCase();
=> A.

var string = 'AbC';
string.replace(/([a-z])([^a-z]*)/gi, '$1.').toUpperCase();
=> A.B.C.

var string = 'A1BC_*';
string.replace(/([a-z])([^a-z]*)/gi, '$1.').toUpperCase();
=> A.B.C.
```